# Is there a way to get contacts of nearby NGOs from google api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-api

I am working on an app that needs to list out the contacts of the nearby NGOs on the basis of the user location.

The same api that google uses to query the "NGOs near me" results. I was wondering if there is an API exposed by google or some other website? Paid or free. I tried searching for it, but could not find it.

Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps API has a Place Search/Nearby Search which may be what you're looking for.
[Google Maps API Places Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)